# Как работает добавление вопросов в избранное?

Tags: поддержка, faq

- Как добавить вопрос в избранное?
- Получают ли участники уведомления по вопросам, которые они добавили в избранное?
- Как посмотреть, какие вопросы были добавлены в избранное?
- Как посмотреть, какие вопросы добавил в избранное другой участник?
- Как посмотреть, кто из участников добавил определённый вопрос в избранное?
- Каким образом система добавления вопросов в избранное влияет на систему голосования?
- Можно ли удалить вопрос из избранных?
- Можно ли выполнить поиск по вопросам в избранном?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод публикации http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы добавить вопрос в избранное, нажмите на звёздочку под счётчиком голосов:

> [image: Favorite]

Число под звёздочкой показывает, сколько участников добавили данный вопрос в избранное. Если участник добавляет вопрос в избранное, по сути это означает, что он хочет следить за этим вопросом. Эта функция никак не связана с системой голосования и не оказывает на нее никакого влияния. При этом если достаточное количество участников добавит ваш вопрос в избранное, вы можете получить [определённые знаки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

После добавления вопроса в избранное вам будет удобнее проверять обновления  в вопросе. Используя данную функцию, вы добавляете вопросы, к которым, возможно, захотите снова вернуться в будущем в закладки.

- Вопрос, добавленный в избранное, будет отображаться на вкладке «Избранное» на [вашей странице участника](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current), что позволит вам легко найти его.
- На вкладке «избранное» содержится счётчик, отображающий количество вопросов, изменённых с момента последнего просмотра этой вкладки. При открытии вкладки «избранное» недавно изменённые вопросы будут подсвечены. Понятие «изменения» включает комментарии и правки вопроса, а также новые и изменённые ответы, то есть функция добавления в избранное позволяет узнавать об обновлениях по вопросам, которые задавали не вы.

> [image: favorites tab counter]

Количество вопросов, добавленных в избранное, не ограничено. Кроме того, вы можете удалить вопрос из избранного в любой момент, просто нажав на звёздочку. Вы можете удалять и заново добавлять вопрос в избранное неограниченное количество раз.

Для поиска по вопросам в избранном добавьте к поисковому запросу оператор `infavorites:mine`.

Посмотреть, какие вопросы добавил в избранное определённый участник сообщества, можно на его странице. Проверить, какие участники добавили в избранное определённый вопрос, можно с помощью [специального запроса](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/299308/favorite-users-by-question) в [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: "получить определённые знаки" - тут явно просится ссылка.

Comment: @AK Знаков таких несколько, одной ссылки нет.

Comment: Я знаю, но это неважно: отправить на страницу всех знаков, заодно и полюбопытствуют, что ещё есть.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а агрегацию, в таком случае, нельзя сделать?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Поясните, пожалуйста, вопрос?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Фактически, одну страницу для всех подходящих знаков